# React.js: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React.js use props to send values to descendant component wrong？

```
const Child = props => <div onClick={ e => console.log(props.value) }>Click to see value.</div>
const Father = props => <div>{ React.cloneElement(props.children, props) }</div>
const GrandFather = props => <div>{ React.cloneElement(props.children, props) }</div>

ReactDOM.render(
  <GrandFather value="This is Test">
    <Father>
      <Child />
    </Father>
  </GrandFather>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

I write the previous demos to test use the `props` to send info to descendant component. But It caused the wrong:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at Object.ReactElement.cloneElement

But I write after demo runs well, so could you tell me what cause the error?

```
const Child = props => <div onClick={ e => console.log(props.value) }>Click to see value.</div>
const Father = props => <div>{ React.cloneElement(props.children, props) }</div>

ReactDOM.render(
  <Father value="This is Test">
    <Child />
  </Father>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this question after some test.

Firstly, I location the question in the `Father` component.

Secondly, the wrong info `Maximum call stack size exceeded` always caused by infinite creating something without recycling.

So, I found the **props** that **I send to `Father` has the value `children` is itself - `Father`**.

`GrandFather` has the props:

```
{
  value: "This is Test",
  children: Father React Element
}
```

When I use `React.cloneElement(child, props)`, `the props.children = Father React Element` is also send to the Father Component.

After I check the React API, the third param of `.cloneElement` is `children` of the cloned element.

After the all, my solution is:

```
const Father = props => <div>{ React.Children.map(props.children, child => React.cloneElement(child, props, child.props.children)) }</div>
```

The whole demo is after:

```
const CloneProps2Children = props => <div>{ React.Children.map(props.children, child => React.cloneElement(child, props, child.props.children)) }</div>
const Child = props => <div onClick={ e => console.log(props.value) }>Click to see value.</div>

export default (
  <CloneProps2Children value="This is test for many middles">
    <CloneProps2Children>
      <CloneProps2Children>
        <Child></Child>
      </CloneProps2Children>
    </CloneProps2Children>
  </CloneProps2Children>
)
```

Comment: When a component have a children as one of the props, also have children components in JSX. The `props.children` in the component will the props you set. Could `React.js` give some solutions to get the both?

Comment: The key is the third param of the `.cloneElement` is `children` of the new Element.

Answer (score 0):

You must clone only one Element.
React.Children is an array

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement

```
   React.cloneElement(
      element,
      [props],
      [...children]
   )
```

Comment: after I change to use `React.Children.map()` to render the children elements, there still the same question. T T